# Best way to secure Connection Strings in PHP using Azure Key Vault?

Tags: php, azure, azure-keyvault

So I've been looking for a way to secure my Connection Strings in my PHP code that connect to my SQL server. I've thought about just making the entire connection string a secret, or making just the password and username a secret.

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do this though as I've seen a post suggesting using a certificate instead but I didn't quite understand it as the post was from 2010.

Addtionally, the connection to the SQL database is sent from a C# app to the PHP file on the server. The app is also used by the public.

Does anyone know the best way to secure Connection Strings in PHP?

Comment: Think you'll need to use curl and the REST api

Comment: Have a look at this - https://github.com/bentaylorwork/php-azure-key-vault